# How to swap pointer variable to declare an array whose size is initially not known?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

So I want to have an array whose size is not known initially (to be taken from the user from command line) but I want to have it globally accessible(outside main).

So here is what I do:

```
 //.h file declaration
 typedef struct res
 {
   int popultaion[NB_TYPE];
   int alive;
   int birthat[NB_TYPE];
 }res_t;

 //.c file
 res_t* res_first = NULL;

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    int no_of_mutants = atoi(argv[1]);
    int i,j = 0;
    srand(time()NULL);
    res_t* tem= res_first;
    for(i = 0; i < no_of_mutants; i++)
    {      

       for(j = 0; i < NB_TYPE; i++)
       {             
         tem->popultaion[j] = rand();
       }
       tem++
    }
    //...other code
  }
```

I get a segmentation fault., When I debug using gdb, it seems like it is here it gets the SIGSEGV.

```
      tem->popultaion[j] = rand();
```

I have two questions:

1. Is this form of trying to construct an array using adding pointer valid? I am getting segfault in the first run though when the address should technically be valid.
2. Is the way of accessing a an array member from a struct valid? (Kind of sure it is but just want to make sure)?

P.S. I am aware of malloc and just could achieve the same thing using malloc but I want to know if this is what giving me problem before going to change everywhere else in the code and if so why?

Comment: Bother explain the down-vote?

Comment: Just a guess about the downvote - you say you know about malloc but don't want to use it. If it had worked anyway, why would we have malloc in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this form of trying to construct an array using adding pointer valid? I am getting segfault in the first run though when the address should technically be valid.

Why should it? It's `NULL`, so your code invokes **undefined behavior.** What you have to do is allocate memory for it when the user entered the number of items in the array.

```
res_first = malloc(sizeof(*res_first) * NUM_OF_ELEMENTS);
```

and of course, free it after use:

```
free(res_first);
```

Comment: Don't confuse the `static` keyword with static storage duration. §6.7.6.3p17: "If the declaration occurs outside of any function, the identifiers have file scope and external linkage.". §6.2.4p3: "An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier _Thread_local, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class specifier static, has static storage duration." §6.7.9p10: "If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then: - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;"

Comment: @modifiablelvalue Are you trying to say that all global variables are zero-initialized? Because they aren't.

Comment: There is no thing as a "global variable" in C. What makes you think I'm trying to say that? I know the standard fairly well, and I'm quite certain that res_first in the above code (prior to the edit) is indeed initialized to a null pointer.

Comment: And anyway, it is now explicitly initialized since OP edited the code. Damn this crap.

Answer (score 1):

You do get segmentation fault because you're not allocating any memory. Your `res_first` isn't even initialized with `NULL` so it points to something random. You need to call `malloc` to allocate the array on the heap with the desired size. Also have a look at `realloc` if you need to reallocate later.

Comment: res_first is implicitly initialized to a null pointer. See my response to H2CO3.